# Build Installshield project using TFS build

Tags: tfs

I am working on Installshield and TFS (VSTS 2008) and now I want to build Installshield 2011 Project along with build definition.

For this I have created build.proj file which contains build definitions to build .sln projects which is working fine.

Now at end of Build definition file I have added like this :

```
<Target Name="AfterCompile">
```

I have added the reference of Installshield project, so that after building Visual Studio projects start building Installshield projects at the end:

```
<Exec Command="&quot;$(DevEnvDir)\Common7\IDE\devenv&quot; E:\Sw\Manual_Build_TFS_R3\Setup.isproj /Build"/>
```

Earlier I have used **VSINSTALLDIR** in palce of **DevEnvDir** still error will come which says

```
Task "Exec"
  Command:
  "\Common7\IDE\devenv" E:\Sw\Manual_Build_TFS_R3\Setup.isproj /Build
  The system cannot find the path specified.
E:\BuildSource\Temp\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj(444,5): error MSB3073: The command ""\Common7\IDE\devenv" E:\Sw\Manual_Build_TFS_R3\Setup.isproj /Build" exited with code 3.
Done executing task "Exec" -- FAILED.
Done building target "AfterCompile" in project "TFSBuild.proj" -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "E:\BuildSource\Temp\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj" (EndToEndIteration target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"E:\BuildSource\Temp\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj" (EndToEndIteration target) (1) ->
(AfterCompile target) -> 
  E:\BuildSource\Temp\BuildType\TFSBuild.proj(444,5): error MSB3073: The command ""\Common7\IDE\devenv" E:\Sw\Manual_Build_TFS_R3\Setup.isproj /Build" exited with code 3.

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
```

I am new to this VSTS and TFS build configurations.

Comment: Thanks Jose..Oops i typed the question in a bit hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use something like this:

```
Command="&quot;%programfiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Common7\IDE\devenv&quot; ..."
```

Would that work for you?

-- EDIT --

Another thought that came to mind is the suggestion that you consider WIX instead of InstallShield.  WIX projects work really well within MSBuild.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any valid reason that the path to your InstallShield project should be hard-coded as it appears in your question.

Can you build the *.isproj file from the command line with MSBuild? If so, then you could just add it to your solution and set it up to only build for a new solution configuration that you use in your TFS build.

Comment: I'm not sure about InstallShield, but there are times that you need to actually run DevEnv.exe to get the compile to work.  The best example of this is compiling BizTalk orchestrations.

Comment: Thanks Jim i am able to build it as well... :)